# "no answer" filter is showing question with answer

Tags: bug, status-declined, new-nav

I came across this bug in the `need answer` tab using this settings:

- Filter : Favorite tags ([bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx) [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) [zedgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zedgraph))
- Show : no answer
- Sort : newest

But it shows questions with answers:

[image]

I tried to refresh the cache (<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) but I didn't change.

Do I make a false interpretation of the `no answer` or is this a real bug?

---

Aaaaaaand here we go again:

[image]

Comment: "unanswered" in SE parlance means "no upvoted or accepted answer". [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: @Deduplicator, Screenshot (at the top) shows just that, "No answer". Which means "No answer", right ?

Comment: @Deduplicator you should take a look at [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256848/235128) and its comments

Comment: "unanswered"=="need answer" <> "no answers", yes.

Comment: I am having the same issue; however, "no answers" returns the same results as "need answers" -- both with Qs that have answers (some accepted even!)

Answer (score 2):

The "unanswered" filter name is a bit misleading. Based on the "unanswered" tag's description here (on meta), the filter shows questions "with no *up-voted* answers" and a quick review of a handful of SE sites indicates this is true: all the answered questions that are shown have only answers with scores <= 0. So it's not a bug, and the questions that show up could be said to need just as much attention as those with no answers.

I know this is a 6yo question, but I found it when observing the same thing today so others might too.

Answer (score 0):

It's caching. Those questions had an answer (or more!) before the cache could be invalidated.

Comment: Then it should be cleared with cache refresh of my browser...? Or it's the cache of the server side?

Comment: @Thomas it's server side

Comment: So it doesn't fully work, by design...