# "Need answers" and "no answers" show same results, with answered/accepted Qs

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

- "No answers" *should* refer to a non-closed question with no *submitted* answer.
- "Need answers" *should* refer to a non-closed question with no *accepted* answer.
- Firefox ESR 38.3.0, CentOS 7 x64
- Related to: ["no answer" filter is showing question with answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295770/no-answer-filter-is-showing-question-with-answer)

[Ruby has over 11,000 non-closed questions without an answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[ruby]%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano) However, the new nav is not expressing this.

- [Ruby - need answers - sort by newest (145,950)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby?filter=need-answers)
  [image: ruby-newest-unaccepted]
- [Ruby - no answers - sort by newest (149,950)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby?filter=no-answer)
  [image: ruby-newest-unanswered]

Notice how both filters have the same results. I am not sure if this is a bug in real-time updating (as others have claimed). But I do not think so, as visiting the links I provided does not help.

I expect at least the "no answers" filter to have the same results as the 11K question link. Rather, both filter types have the same results

- Questions without answers
- Questions with answers (upvoted)
- Questions with accepted answer (upvoted)

Comment: Also relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256848

Comment: @DrewGaynor thank you for the links. I just wanted to fill a bug report out to make sure. If this gets closed, alright. Also, I agree with the second, in that both options are a little vague. As I described in my question, "need answer" _should_ be "unaccepted", while "no answer" _should_ be "has no answers".

Comment: @DrewGaynor In this case, it actually looks like _neither_ filter is working correctly, as "needs answer" should show questions that are considered "unanswered" by the site: No _upvoted or accepted_ answers. In turn, "no answers" should show questions with _no_ answers. This is actually potentially a bug from the new deployment of the redesign of the new nav, so quite likely _not_ a duplicate of that one. Edit: Actually, both of those "filters" are showing _all_ ruby questions, so I would say definitely a bug.

Comment: I agree with you on what the meaning of the filters should be. And, I'm actually seeing what (I think) are more issues with these filters. If I navigate directly to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?filter=no-answer for example, the filter just gets removed. Same for the "needs answer" filter. And, those views look identical to me.

Comment: @DrewGaynor feel free to help edit my question so that it is not a duplicate of another. I do no not feel the linked dup is completely related, as mine goes more in depth

Comment: @Kendra True, strange that both views are showing questions with accepted answers. Like I said in my previous comment, both views actually look identical to me, and those filters get cleared if I refresh or navigate directly.

Comment: @Kendra thank you for the help. I see that your link is more similar to mine. I will still keep this Q up, just in case. But glad to know some it is is already being worked on!

Comment: @Kendra please edit my Q/title too, if you think it is too ambiguous or not descriptive enough

Comment: Oh, yeah, there's never a need to delete a duplicate question. Duplicates aren't bad, after all. If your duplicate absolutely _needs_ deleted, the community will handle it. Yours definitely doesn't.

Comment: I can't edit on Meta- Under 2k rep, and there are no suggested edits on meta. :) I think your title is fine, really.

Comment: looks like fixing http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308878/new-navigation-sort-bug also fixed this one